# How to make router DNS settings permanent?

Tags: windows, router, dns

I have just bought a D'link router. But the ISP requires me to use their own DNS service.
But the problem is ... That If put that DNS in the router settings, the DNS resets everytime the router is restarted, and I have to put that DNS in the settings again.
How do I make my router DNS settings permanent so that it doesn't reset everytime I switch off the router.
Please Help!!

Comment: Why don't you just configure your windows installation to use the dns information instead of the router's information, not that you should have to, the router properly configured should automatically receive the information from your isp.  Your router "reseting" when its restarted is odd that shouldn't happen

Comment: But my isp is a bit different. It doesn't have pppoe but it makes users login through a web portal....

Comment: Your router's settings still shouldn't be lost if the router restarts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using windows:

1. Go to the `Network Connections` page inside the control panel.
2. Select `Change adapter configuration` on the left panel.
3. Right click your device and select `Properties`.
4. Once there, click the `IPv4` item and click the `Properties` button.
5. Select the `Use the following DNS server addresses` and type the addresses you want. I suggest you use [Google's DNS servers](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/): 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4.
6. Accept to save the settings and reconnect to your network.

[image: DNS]

Windows will use the specified DNS servers instead of asking the router for its configured servers.